# scalaz 7.2.6 flatMap is not a method of Validation?

Tags: scalaz

This works on scalaz 7.0.6, but not on the latest release of scalaz, 7.2.6.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def allDigits(s: String): Validation[String, String] =
  if (s.forall(_.isDigit)) s.success else "Not all digits".failure

def maxSizeOfTen(s: String): Validation[String, String] =
  if (s.length <= 10) s.success else "Too big".failure

def toInt(s: String) = try s.toInt.success catch {
  case _: NumberFormatException => "Still not an integer".failure
}

val validated1 = for {
  x <- allDigits("4234")
  y <- maxSizeOfTen(x)
  z <- toInt(y)
} yield z
```

I get these errors on scalaz 7.2.6:

```
value flatMap is not a member of scalaz.Validation[String,String]
      x <- allDigits("4234")
value flatMap is not a member of scalaz.Validation[String,String]
      y <- maxSizeOfTen(x)
...
```

How do I make it work on the latest version of scalaz?

---

**Update: Solution based on the accepted answer:**

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def allDigits(s: String): \/[String, String] =
  if (s.forall(_.isDigit)) s.right else "Not all digits".left

def maxSizeOfTen(s: String): \/[String, String] =
  if (s.length <= 10) s.right else "Too big".left

def toInt(s: String) = try s.toInt.right catch {
  case _: NumberFormatException => "Still not an integer".left
}

val validated1 = for {
  x <- allDigits("4234")
  y <- maxSizeOfTen(x)
  z <- toInt(y)
} yield z
```

Comment: Problem of your approached solution is it will fail fast (first validation which is not passed the code will stop and return the error). So in the case of "123456789ten" it will give you only first error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previous answer pointed Validation is useful when you want to run things in parallel and get all the errors at once.

Applicative approach:

```
def allDigits(s: String): Validation[String, String] =
  if (s.forall(_.isDigit)) s.success else s"|error: '$s' Not all digits ".failure

def maxSizeOfTen(s: String): Validation[String, String] =
  if (s.length <= 10) s.success else s"|error: '$s' Too big".failure

def toInt(s: String) = try s.toInt.success catch {
  case _: NumberFormatException => "|Still not an integer".failure
}

val input = "4234"
val validated1 = (allDigits(input) |@| maxSizeOfTen(input)) { (x, _) => toInt(x) }
println(validated1)

val input2 = "123456789ten"
val validated2 = (allDigits(input2) |@| maxSizeOfTen(input2)) { (x, _) => toInt(x) }
println(validated2)
```

You will have next output:

```
Success(Success(4234))
Failure(|error: '123456789ten' Not all digits |error: '123456789ten' Too big)
```

Answer (score 8):

Validation is not supposed to be used with a `flatMap`, because it aims to accumulate the failures and therefore has `Applicative` instance for independent (context-free) computations. `\/` is supposed to be used in your case (dependent (or context-sensitive) computations).
Still, by adding this import, you can achieve what you want:
`import Validation.FlatMap._`